# ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason I can't get a POST or UPDATE to successfully work via  Postman. The error I get is as follows:

```
    Started POST "/names" for ::1 at 2022-10-19 16:26:48 -0500
Processing by NamesController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"_json"=>[{"name"=>"Joseph Schmoseph"}], "name"=>{}}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms | Allocations: 255)


  
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name):
  
app/controllers/names_controller.rb:57:in `names_params'
app/controllers/names_controller.rb:19:in `create'
```

Here is my names_controller with all routes:

```
class NamesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_name, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /names
  def index
    @names = Name.all

    render json: @names
  end

  # GET /names/1
  def show
    render json: @name
  end

  # POST /names
  def create
    @name = Name.new(name_params)

    if @name.save
      render json: @name, status: :created, location: @name
    else
      render json: @name.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /names/1
  def update
    if @name.update(name_params)
      render json: @name
    else
      render json: @name.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /names/1
  def destroy
    @name.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_name
      @name = Name.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def name_params
      params.require(:name).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

All other routes are working fine execpt the UPDATE and CREATE. I'm using Postgresql as my db. I've never had this issue before with simple db routes so I'm a bit stumped. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Your parameters are not formatted properly. You have `{"_json"=>[{"name"=>"Joseph Schmoseph"}], "name"=>{}}` but should send `{"name"=>{"name"=>"full name"}}`

Comment: Ok would you care to elaborate on where {full name} is coming from? The error is coming from my create route and the strong params so where exactly would that "full name" be placed?

Comment: @JorgeL you are misunderstanding the comment `params.require(:name).permit(:name)` means the params must have a key of `name` and will allow a nested key of `name` e.g.  you are looking for a structure of `{"name" => { "name": "Joseph Schmoseph"}}` but that is not what you are passing in. Instead you are passing `{"_json"=>[{"name"=>"Joseph Schmoseph"}], "name"=>{}}`.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't sure what Maxcence was referring to. I realized that its a naming convention issue when I created another test api and it was fully functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maxence means

In postman

change

```
  {
    name: "Joseph Schmoseph"
  }
```

to

```
 {
   name: {
      name: "Joseph Schmoseph"
   }
 }
```

In names_controller.rb

```
 // Parameters: {"name"=>{"name"=>"Joseph Schmoseph"}, "commit"=>"Create"} 
  
 // fixed this issue: ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: name):
  
  def create 
    ....
  end
```